# MSAL auth flow blocked by Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We developed an application for Windows Server 2019 and 2022 which uses MSAL with .NET for authentication. When we run the app in WS 2019 which has IE as default browser, the IE Enhanced Security Configuration does not trust some authentication links by default like https://login.microsoftonline.com and https://aadcdn.msauth.net which blocks the authentication until the links are trusted by the browser. How can this be avoided?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I created one VM with **Windows server 2019** image.

[image]

When I try to login to https://login.microsoftonline.com/ in Internet explorer, I too got **similar issue** what you have mentioned in images:

[image]

[image]

To avoid these, you need to turn off the **IE enhanced security configuration** like this:

*In VM Go to Server Manager -> Local Server -> IE enhanced security configuration -> Off*

[image]

After **disabling** that option, I'm able to access the websites successfully like this:

[image]

[image]